# target specific element in backboneJS

Tags: backbone.js

Based on [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/), I try to get the element clicked which populated by subview. The events, which will trigger the function, is created in parent view

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. make a model
2. make a collection based on the model
3. make a view of model
4. make a view of collection by collecting all the view of item on step 3.
5. append the collection view to the DOM

check this basic fiddle. it might help
[sample fiddle](http://goo.gl/9LmbX0)

Comment: i used Derrick Bailey approach on the event aggragator